# Angular2 test async Http.MockBackend.connections promise not yielding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise, observable

I'm having trouble using `injectAsync` with the `http.MockBackend`. The `auth.ngOnInit()` method calls `Http.get()`, but in this test the `MockBackend.connections.toPromise().then()` method is never called:

```
it('should check if the user is authenticated',
   injectAsync([Auth, MockBackend], (auth, backend) => {
     let promise = backend.connections.toPromise().then(
       (connection) => {
         let link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = connection.request.url;
         expect(link.pathname).toBe('/api/auth/user/');
       });
     auth.ngOnInit();
     return promise;
}));
```

I've confirmed in the debugger that the `MockBackend.connections.next()` method is being called.  When I run the test, however, it fails with `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`  What am I missing here?

Comment: Quick check - what if you would remove the `debugger` - same issue?

Comment: @alecxe Good catch, thanks!  Same outcome without it though.

Comment: Thanks, how about the `auth.ngOnInit()` part - would it timeout if you comment it out?

Comment: @alecxe Also a good thought.  Also same result though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @alxhub and @ericmartinezr [in gitter](https://gitter.im/angular/angular), the issue is that I need to narrow the observable to a single result before I can call `toPromise()`.  So this works:

```
it('should check if the user is authenticated',
   injectAsync([Auth, MockBackend], (auth, backend) => {
     let promise = backend.connections.first().toPromise().then(
       (connection) => {
         let link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = connection.request.url;
         expect(link.pathname).toBe('/api/auth/user/');
       });
     auth.ngOnInit();
     return promise;
}));
```